# WordPress comments just vanished even tho there are about 250+ of them. Where did they go?

Tags: comments

I manage a wordpress installation that handles quite a bit of traffic. We use WP-Cache and WP Thread Comment and recently, the owner noticed there was 250 comments on 1 post, but only one comment was showing. Here is a screenshot: http://cl.ly/3rtk

All the comments can be seen from the control panel of WP. But I think WP Thread Comment doesn't have enough memory to pull all the comments so it just shows the latest one. Anyone have this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Your question is specific to Wordpress administration, and would be better at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: are they awaiting moderation? what can you see if you manually query the database?

Comment: I just realized by going thru the plugins that it was indeed the WP Thread Comment plugin. Guess it doesn't have enough memory to pull all 250+ comments so it just defaults to the last photo.

Comment: Was the site showing multiple comments before? Are they in the moderation que or spam que? have you tried refreshing the cache?

Comment: When you look in the database what number does the "comment count" show next to the post in <prefix>_posts ?

Comment: Analyze your database tables and see if any need a repair(run one if they do), missing database entries are sometimes the result of a corrupt table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress comments just vanished even tho there are about 250+ of them. Where did they go?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/wordpress-comments-just-vanished-even-tho-there-are-about-250-of-them-where-did)

Answer (score 3):

first thing I would do is to deactivate the Cache and see if that makes a difference. If disabling solves the problem, reset the cache for the comments of the particular post.

Probably something went wrong for the caching strategy and it ended up in some useless state.

Answer (score 0):

Goto phpmyadmin and repair the database, your comments should be back.